# Joomla K2 - Displaying an item's extra field data elsewhere on the site

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

i'm building a website for a house builder and each house plot (k2 item) has a few extra fields associated with it such as 'price' and 'availability'.

i would like to display this extra field data elsewhere on the site perhaps in a table that lists 5-6 plots and displays their current price and availability.

the idea is to be able to change the price of a house in the extra fields section and then have this change reflected in other parts of the site that call on this extra field data.

i've read this article..

http://jurawa.com/notes/item/27-update-making-k2-more-like-a-true-cck-custom-admin-templates-and-calling-specific-extra-field-data

..which explains a process of displaying extra field data but i've not managed to get this to work. i also think that this method would only work if displaying extra field data while already inside the item that it relates to. i'm trying to display this extra field data around other parts of the site.

i'm trying to replicate something like the table that appears on this page (just above the map)

http://www.orionhomes.co.uk/development/brunswick-place

running the latest version of jooma and k2 and have full access to server and database.

hope someone can help..!

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Raxo All-In-One module to accomplish this in the past:
http://www.raxo.org/raxo-all-mode-k2.html

This, along with ability to insert a module in an article, would allow you to place the specific K2 content/fields wherever you need them and have them updated dynamically by K2.

Another option would be to create a new template for K2 and only output the extra fields in your item list. This would allow you to create the table view you are looking for.

Comment: Was this answer able to help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely display those extra fields wherever you need them on the site.

[This step-by-step tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120623002410/http://www.alltogetherasawhole.org/profiles/blogs/k2-tutorial-a-step-by-step) may help you to create the extra fields.

Then you just need to enable the extra fields in your view and modify your template.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great plug-in for Joomla/K2 that does this for you at:
http://joomcar.net
It's called K2 Filter and Search Module and it will display a table with the extra fields as you have demonstrated in at:
http://www.orionhomes.co.uk/development/brunswick-place

Comment: I have used this plugin in the past, but I don't think it would allow you to filter to a specific subset of items without the user interacting with the filtering options first.